# My geometries are not plotting correctly in r tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to plot a series of points onto a tmap however, the points are not being plotted at the correct long/lat. Here is the code:

```
#loading data
ne_110<-st_read(file.choose(), crs=4326)

locations<-read.csv(file.choose())
locations<-st_as_sf(locations, coords=c('long','lat'), crs=4326)
head(locations)

tm_shape(ne_110)+
  tm_fill(col='darkslategray2')+
  tm_borders(col="black")+
  tm_layout(scale=0.5, bg.color="dodgerblue4",inner.margin=0.0005)+
  
  tm_shape(locations)+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, col = "firebrick1")
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Here is the dataset:

[image]

Comment: That geometry are not in lon lat projection.

Comment: Try this before the plot part: `locations <- st_transform(locations, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")`

Comment: To make a reproducible example that could be useful in the future you could post the output of `dput(head(locations))` obtained just after the input from file instead of a picture of that data. Pictures cannot be used for demonstrations or error checking.

Comment: Looks like you've got lat / lon the other way - try switching the columns